# I need a Java library that simplifies math equations

Tags: library, java, math

let's say, for example, I give this equation as an input:

```
4x + x - 20 + 10
```

And I want to get `5x - 10` as a result

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) - Java computer algebra and symbolic math library.

```
import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.expression.F;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IAST;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.ISymbol;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator(false, (short) 100);

      // Convert an expression to the internal Java form:
      // Note: single character identifiers are case sensitive
      // (the "D()" function identifier must be written as upper case character)
      String javaForm = util.toJavaForm("4*x + x - 20 + 10");
      // prints: Plus(ZZ(-20L),x,Times(C4,x),C10)
      System.out.println("Out[1]: " + javaForm.toString());

      // Use the Java form to create an expression with F.* static methods:
      ISymbol x = F.Dummy("x");
      IAST function = F.Plus(F.ZZ(-20L), x, F.Times(F.C4, x), F.C10);
      IExpr result = util.eval(function);
      // print: -10+5*x
      System.out.println("Out[2]: " + result.toString());
    } catch (SyntaxError e) {
      // catch Symja parser errors here
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (RuntimeException rex) { 
      System.out.println(rex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataMelt (http://jwork.org/dmelt) does this. Here is an example (I use Jython, but you can use Java too)

```
from jhplot.math import *  
from jhplot import *
j=Symbolic("jscl") # using jscl engine
print j.simplify("(x + 1)^(1/x)") == "(1+x)^(1/x)" 
print j.simplify("(x^2-1)/(x-1)") == "1+x"
```

This code returns "true" for all such simplifications

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you have with this product.

Comment: (I'm a web admin where many community/free programs are located. Not associated with this particular program in any other  way).

Answer (score 0):

[Maple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) does this well, but it is a commercial product.

For more alternatives check the [List of computer algebra systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) on Wikipedia, but that list does not show *how* something is implemented, or whether it has a Java API. You'd have to look this up yourself.